# Plotly Plots are not showing on Github

Tags: github, plotly

I am new to plotly and find it very interesting. I am able to plot on iPython Notebook, same plots are not visible when I published that Notebook on GitHub. 
GitHub link: https://github.com/afizing/matplot2plotly/blob/master/matplot2plotly.ipynb

Any help would be great help.

Comment: Please post your code directly in the question rather than just posting a link to it.

Comment: I found the solution to my question in Plotly community group. I learnt that GitHuB doesn't support ipython notebook rendering .. solution is to view using nbviewer. i.e. http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/afizing/matplot2plotly/ instead of github.com/afizing/matplot2plotly/

Comment: @Afiz - maybe add that as an answer, and then accept it? That way, the question gets closed, and it's clearer to people who stumble across this page (like I just did), what the answer is.

Answer (score 1):

I found that as well. You can't see the charts on Github. I've linked to my external site, or as others say, you can host them on NBviewer as well.